# How to prevent publish resetting cookies using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, cookies, windows-server-2008

I have a web site which uses cookies using ASP.NET, however everytime I publish a new site and upload all or some of the new .dlls it invalidates all the existing cookies.
The cookies are used to track simple logins, but I want to maintain the cookies that were created before a publish so they are still usable afterwards - this seems to affect webkit based browsers and in my testing I can replicate this issue after each partial or full publish.

Below is the Code I use to Set A Cookie:

```
If HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies(COOKIE_NAME) Is Nothing Then
            Dim _cookie As New HttpCookie(COOKIE_NAME, CookieValue)
            _cookie.Path = COOKIE_PATH
            _cookie.Expires = COOKIE_EXPIRES
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(_cookie)
        Else
            With HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies(COOKIE_NAME)
                .Path = COOKIE_PATH
                .Value = Value
                .Expires = COOKIE_EXPIRES
            End With
        End If
```

And here is the code I use to Read a Cookie:

```
If HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies(COOKIE_NAME) IsNot Nothing Then
    Return HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies(COOKIE_NAME).Value
End If
```

Where COOKIE_NAME is set to "MyCookie" and COOKIE_PATH is set to "/" and the COOKIE_EXPIRES is set to "#1/1/2035#"

I can read / write cookies fine, but once I do a Publish all previously created cookies become unreadable by Webkit browsers, although they can be Written to again, but I'm not sure this will be the case all the time - I want a publish to have no effect on the cookies at all - is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the Request/Reponse Headers from the WebKit browser to see what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined a machine key in your web.config. Otherwise ViewState, Session, Forms authentication, or other encrypted and/or secured values will be invalidated when your app recycles.

Here is a good article on [codeplex](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/machineKey.aspx).

[This](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey) is an online tool that generates a machine key for you.

```
<system.web>
 <machineKey YOUR VALUES HERE/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I'm not encrypting this information that I'm reading / writing, the value is already protected when it goes into the cookie and this is done with fixed code from the Cookie value.

Comment: I did some further reading and the mechanism I referred to seems to only apply to Role Cookies, so indeed, this does not seem to be a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks anyway - that could have been the issue as I can see where that value changing could cause a problem, useful to know anyway if someone else has that issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at using a CookieContainer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx

I've dealt with them in the past using multiple web requests.

Comment: This looks interesting, will give this a try - if it can maintain cookie state between publishes - it will do the job!

Comment: I think the CookieContainer is only for use with a HttpWebRequest, which is something you use only for demand requests like screen scraping.  I don't think this is going to help.